# HTML textbox pattern

Tags: html, angularjs

How to Restrict Html text box to accept only Patterns like

A1+A2*A3

1. it should contain alphanumeric(A1 to A5)

2)it should accept arithmetic operators in above mentioned format

I am angular js for scripting

Comment: You should use the regular expression to do so.

Comment: Hi, I tried various patterns that is not working for me , Can please post any examples

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: <input type="text" pattern="[A\d\W]+"/>

Comment: @TheKNVB Nothing worked for me,Can u please suggest any           
 <input type="text" pattern="[A1-A5+\W]+"/>

Comment: You may try:
<input type="text" name="qq" required pattern="A[12345]"/>

Comment: Hi @TheKNVB, i Tried this is working for adding A1,A2 to A5. But i need like formula field A1+A3*A4+A2

Comment: For studying regular expression, You may start from the following page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is what you need.

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <input type="text" name="qq" required value="A1+A3*A4+A2" pattern="(A[12345][+\-*/])*A[12345]([+\-*/]A[12345])*"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```